# Why keyPress Event in PyQt does not work for key Enter?

Tags: events, python-3.x, pyqt4, keypress

Why, when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, does the `keyPressEvent` method not do what I need? It just moves the cursor to a new line.

```
class TextArea(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.show()

    def SLOT_SendMsg(self):
        return lambda: self.get_and_send()

    def get_and_send(self):
        text = self.toPlainText()
        self.clear()
        get_connect(text)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter: 
            self.get_and_send()
        else:
            super().keyPressEvent(event)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Qt.Key_Enter`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#Key-enum) is the Enter located on the keypad:

```
Qt::Key_Return  0x01000004   
Qt::Key_Enter   0x01000005  Typically located on the keypad.
```

Use:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, qKeyEvent):
    print(qKeyEvent.key())
    if qKeyEvent.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return: 
        print('Enter pressed')
    else:
        super().keyPressEvent(qKeyEvent)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if (event.key() == 16777220) or (event.key() == 43):  # for main keyboard and keypad
```

Works for my keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

My grain of salt to complement the answers from @warvariuc and @tCot. A bit more pythonic:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, qKeyEvent):
    if qKeyEvent.key() in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Return, QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter): 
        pass # your code
    else:
        super().keyPressEvent(qKeyEvent)
```